# js+html5 image processing

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing

I need to do an image processing, solved at the server side (for now with GD).

Basically, it consist on:
 - A background
 - A Picture
 - A Mask (black/white) with the shape to remove one part of the Picture
 - A new picture that cover the part removed before

Those images are created for this purpose, so they have the correct transparent png, ...

I need to analyse aswell if it is possible to do this process at client side with js+html5. I have been exploring some libraries those work with canvas (fabricjs, jcanvas), but I haven't found a clear way to do.

I even not sure if this kind of job could be done at client side.

I will appreciate clarification on this, and if so ... some idea ...

Thanks in advance,
·_-

EDIT:

I have been working following the pixel processing tutorial, but I can't get the proper operation to achieve the goal. What I am trying:

```
var background = new Image();
background.src = "assets/imgs/bg1_3PSC1PDZZZZZZZZZ_ZZZZZZZZ_ZZZZZZZZ_005.jpg";
var scooter = new Image();
scooter.src = "assets/imgs/3PSC1PD2TB01A010_ZZZZZZZZ_0PAL0RFC_005_01.png";
var mask = new Image();
mask.src = "assets/imgs/DE_RJGC_3PSC1PDZZZ01ZZ10_ZZZZZZZZ_ZZZZZZZZ_005_10.png";
var newElt = new Image();
newElt.src = "assets/imgs/RJGC_3PSC1PDZZZ01ZZ10_ZZZZZZZZ_ZZZZZZZZ_005_10.png";

$(background).load(function() {
   ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
});

$(scooter).load(function() {
   ctx.drawImage(scooter, 0, 500);
});

$(mask).load(function() {
   ctx.drawImage(mask, 0, 1175);
});

$(newElt).load(function() {
   ctx.drawImage(newElt, 0, 1850);
});

$('#composite').click(function(){
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var bgData      = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1200, 500);
var pixBackground   = bgData.data;
var scooterData = ctx.getImageData(0, 500, 1200, 675);
var pixScooter  = scooterData.data;
var maskData    = ctx.getImageData(0, 1175, 1200, 675);
var pixMask     = maskData.data;
var newEltData  = ctx.getImageData(0, 1850, 1200, 675);
var pixNewElt   = newEltData.data;

var numPixels = scooterData.width * scooterData.height;

// remove a part of the picture thanks to the mask
// --> do the job    
for (var i=0; i < numPixels; i++) {
  pixScooter[i*4+3] = (255 - pixMask[i*4+3]) * pixScooter[i*4+3];
}

// add the new picture that cover the removed part before
// --> horrible effect and not really well covered
for (var i=0; i < numPixels; i++) {
  pixScooter[i*4]   += pixNewElt[i*4];
  pixScooter[i*4+1] += pixNewElt[i*4+1];
  pixScooter[i*4+2] += pixNewElt[i*4+2];
  pixScooter[i*4+3] += pixNewElt[i*4+3];
}


ctx.putImageData(scooterData, 0, 2525);
});
```

I have tried different combinations  ... any magic idea ?

Thanks in advance to have a look here,
·_-

**EDIT II**

I've changed the strategy and move to play with globalCompositionOperation, playing for a while thanks to http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-global-composite-operations-tutorial/ I achieve with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var bg   = loadImage('/path/to/image/bg.jpg', main);
var sup  = loadImage('/path/to/image/sup.png', main);
var sco  = loadImage('/path/to/image/sco.png', main);
var sust = loadImage('/path/to/image/sust.png', main);

var imagesLoaded = 0;
function main() {
imagesLoaded += 1;

if(imagesLoaded == 3) {
ctx.globalAlpha = 1;

ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
ctx.drawImage(sup, 0, 0);

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
ctx.drawImage(sco, 0, 0);

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
ctx.drawImage(sust, 0, 0);

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';
ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0);

}
}

function loadImage(src, onload) {
// http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/image-onload-isnt-being-called
var img = new Image();

img.onload = onload;
img.src = src;

return img;
}
});
```

Comment: There is a fairly detailed example of using canvas to do client side editing here http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/canvas-from-scratch-pixel-manipulation/ canvas is the only API that has pixel level editing. Other method are overlaying images to create an alusion, IE fading a black and white image which is ontop of a color image for appearance only.

Comment: this tuto sounds good ... thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just doing a quick search shows some promising libraries out there.  For example:

http://developers.aviary.com/docs/web

http://camanjs.com/

http://www.pixastic.com/editor-test/

Comment: thank you for more references, but as I have been exploring with fabrics and jcanvas, I can't see a clear way to apply to achieve my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas on HTML5 is something really good: you can load an image on it and play with the pixels as you wish. I have written [this article](http://www.erickfernandes.com/post/2013/05/29/Uma-camera-como-sensor-de-velocidade.aspx) suggesting how one can measure speed of a vehicle applying image subtraction. The article and the code is in portuguese but maybe you could understand the general principle.

An advice: file protocol disallows working with images so you gonna need to publish your code to a webserver.

Comment: ... it has inspired me ... yes ;) thank you, I am going to try to do some maths with pixels ... `:-/  :p

Comment: Great! This gonna be funny, but remember the libraries, they will save you a lot of time. Feel free to get in contact. I like this field.

Comment: your idea with the tut wayne referenced, i am more optimistic :)